# vscode terminal crashes on .nprmc env config

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, terminal

I recently added an `.npmrc` file to my project to install a private package using github's package registry service. 
it looks like this:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}
@myorg:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

When I load this repo in a regular terminal, I have no issues. my .zshrc sources my .bash_profile where I have

```
// ~/.bash_profile
export GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN="mytoken"
```

When I load the integrated terminal in vscode, which is pointed to use zsh

```
// ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh",
"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
```

But I keep seeing the error

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but nice to see, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92350 associates .nprmc files to INI-files in v1.44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading vscode ended up fixing the issue! Not just reloading the terminal, but reloading the whole editor seems to finally load the changed env config.